# Writing grammars with prolog

Tags: prolog, grammar, context-free-grammar, dcg

Is it possible to use Prolog to define a grammar for a non-natural language, for example, SQL?
If so, please guide me to some starting point.

Comment: how can I say that, for example: select - from - where are a key word, and they can be upcase or lowercase. thanks

Comment: Is there any links or documents that explain the syntax and the use of the DCG in a simple way. please. I'm googling now but I'm little lost. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Prolog supports [Definite Clause Grammars (DCG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar). With this you can write context-free grammars like this:

```
sql --> select_statement.
select_statement --> select, from_statement.
from --> [from].
select --> [select].
```

This can be directly interpreted by a Prolog interpreter.
I am not sure what kind of grammar SQL needs. It should be possible to write some kind of context-sensitive grammars, too.

Comment: Thanks @marli.  what does mean the brackets in this [from] ?

Comment: They are the [terminal symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_and_nonterminal_symbols) of the grammar. That are simple constants in Prolog, so writing them capitalized is wrong here.

Comment: Alright thank you @marli. The comma means "and" I think ? "OR" can be expressed by "|" . yeah?  And how can express that something can be repeated 0 or many times?

Comment: Yes, the comma means "and". But "or" is expressed with a semicolon ";". This is handled like in Prolog. Actually the grammar style is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: This is a grammar and not a regular expression. So you can only use recursion. E.g. moreThanOne --> moreThanOne; one.

Comment: Try this: http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse29 for dokumentation.